# Using DDE for getting url from firefox is throwing exception and using "AutomationElement" is performance wise slow

Tags: c#, firefox

I am trying to get the current tab's URL in firefox browser using DDE the following exception is thrown.

> Message = "The client failed to request \"Firefox|WWW_GetWindowInfo!URL\"."

The following is the code.

```
            DdeClient dde = new DdeClient("Firefox", "WWW_GetWindowInfo");
            try
            {

                dde.Connect();
                string url = dde.Request("URL", int.MaxValue);
                ProcessManagementModel p = new ProcessManagementModel();
                p.WindowTitle = WindowTitle;
                p.ProcessName = "firefox.exe";
                p.BrowserURL = url;
                UpdateProcessInfo(p, string.Empty);
            }
```

*The code fails only after Firefox update to version 52.5.2

*The code works fine in the previous firefox version(52.5.0)

*I avoid using "**AutomationElement**" since it is performance wise slow.

It would be great if someone explains why the exception occurs and let me know an alternative solution to get the URL from firefox.

Thanks.

Comment: You have to rebuild your C# project.  The libraries aren't the same.  The c# compiler is recognizing the library changes and not doing a complete rebuild.  I usually just delete the bin folder in the project to force the compiler to rebuild everything. Make sure you didn't manually put any files into the bin folder so make a backup before deleting.

Comment: There are literally hundreds of duplicates

Comment: @jdweng I deleted my bin folder and rebuilded the solution, but the exception persists.